# How do I get Jersey 2.5.1 on tomcat to log request/response including entities (request/response body)

Tags: tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have a Jersey 2.5.1 application deployed on tomcat.  I have added following config in my web.xml:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
  <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

It's printing request and response headers.  However, it's not printing the request/response entities/bodies in the response.

I tried playing with different params but no luck, like:

```
INFO: 1 * Server has received a request on thread http-bio-8080-exec-3
1 > accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
1 > accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
1 > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
1 > cache-control: no-cache
1 > connection: keep-alive
1 > cookie: JSESSIONID=1F5CCACA7DF2EABA9475C270A95C91B2
1 > host: localhost:8080
1 > pragma: no-cache
1 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36


Jan 24, 2014 1:01:31 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8080-exec-3
1 < 200
1 < Content-Type: application/json
```

---

Thanks for your answer. looks like i pasted a wrong config above. here is what i have in my web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.my.package.web.resources;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It logs the headers. but it does not log the entities. here is what i see in my logs:

```
Jan 28, 2014 2:36:38 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 5 * Server has received a request on thread http-bio-8080-exec-10
5 > GET http://localhost:8080/sample/api/foo
5 > accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
5 > accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
5 > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
5 > cache-control: max-age=0
5 > connection: keep-alive
5 > cookie: JSESSIONID=1F5CCACA7DF2EABA9475C270A95C91B2
5 > host: localhost:8080
5 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36

Jan 28, 2014 2:36:38 PM Jan 28, 2014 2:36:38 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 5 * Server responded with a response on thread http-bio-8080-exec-10
5 < 200
5 < Content-Type: application/json
```

My Jersey application is deployed on Tomcat 7_50 server.

if i have tracing and loggingfilter configured using init-param in my web.xml. do i still need to register it using Recource Config?

public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig as below:

```
    public MyApplication() {
        // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
        packages("my.package");

        // Register my custom provider - not needed if it's in my.package.
        register(SecurityRequestFilter.class);
        // Register an instance of LoggingFilter.
        register(new LoggingFilter(LOGGER, true));

        // Enable Tracing support.
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't configure that in `web.xml`.
2. You're mixing 2 versions of Jersey (init-params in your `web.xml` are from Jersey 1 - `com.sun.jersey` package prefix)
3. Take a look at [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) you can find there how to register `LoggingFilter` to make sure entities are also logged.

Comment: please see my comments below:

Comment: The link provided 3. contains code that does not compile and has a few confusing errors in it. I didn't find it very useful.

Comment: follow 3, i still can't get logging of entity. Any help more?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CustomLoggingFilter.java` as per Lokesh Gupta’s [instructions](http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-custom-logging-request-and-response-entities-using-filter)

I ended up registering the filter slightly differently though:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.addAll(super.getClasses());
        classes.add(CustomLoggingFilter.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Register your `MyApplication.java` in your `web.xml`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>org.something.MyApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Hi, I am doing almost same. But I am unable to print it in Json format. Any insights ? Thanks